# Adding recessed lighting to room with ceiling fan/light already installed

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

Ok,

First off I have done small electrical projects like add outlets, but never anything major. I have a loft with a ceiling fan/light that is just not bright enough to light up the entire room. The light is controlled by one switch, the fan by another. The house is 10 years old running 14/2 to the switches.

I would like to add a few LED recessed lights into the room to brighten it up a bit, and would like them to be on their own dimmer switch.

Can I wire the Fan/Light into one switch from one hot wire, then use the extra hot wire connected to the other switch to then power the series of LED can lights (then pig tail the neutral and ground)? Attached is a diagram of my proposed wiring.
Obviously I want to stay within code to be safe.
Thanks guys/gals!

Sterling

[image]

Comment: Assuming your fan was rated for incandescent bulbs, you might be able to put brighter CF or LED bulbs into the fan and stay within the rated watts.  This would be an easier/cheaper solution than putting a couple of cans in.

Answer (score 3):

That will work. Code depends on where you live, but I can't see anything wrong with making the junction away from the switch.

You might have issues doing all this in the fan box. It might be cleaner to put a small box in the ceiling and do your connections, then have a small run down to the fan.

And be smart with placement of recessed lighting above a fan. You can get a strobing effect which is annoying (and gives some folks headaches).